# I have a problem with hp jet pro m102a on ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, printing, hp, hplip

I have a problem with hp jet pro m102a on ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't work even i install the latest version of hplip 3.17.6 and the driver is show up but when i print the test page it doesn't print anything if you could help me please i will appreciate that!
Thank you!

Comment: HP provide a trouble-shooting guide http://hplipopensource.com/node/224 and if you open a terminal and type `hp-check`and you can also run `hp-check -t` so please let us know what you get with these enquiries

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Download latest hplip drivers from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing It will take you to download page where you need to choose your distro.

**Step 2:** Once downloaded, open terminal and type,

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/   
$ chmod +x [downloaded file name].run
$ ./[downloaded file name].run
```

**Step 3:** Follow instructions on screen.